# SELECT Query should return the records of one of the OR conditions in Postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql

Sample Code :

```
CREATE TABLE Foo
(
    Id SERIAL NOT NULL,
    Name TEXT NOT NULL,
    DefaultValue BOOLEAN NOT NULL,
    Active BOOLEAN NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO Foo(Name, DefaultValue, Active)
VALUES ('aa', TRUE, FALSE);
INSERT INTO Foo(Name, DefaultValue, Active)
VALUES ('bb', TRUE, FALSE);
```

I need a query similar to this to get my required result:

```
SELECT *
FROM Foo 
WHERE Active = TRUE OR DefaultValue = TRUE;
```

And the query should return the records of aa, bb.

After adding these two records:

```
INSERT INTO Foo(Name, DefaultValue, Active)
VALUES ('cc', FALSE, TRUE);
INSERT INTO Foo(Name, DefaultValue, Active)
VALUES ('dd', FALSE, TRUE);
```

The query should return the records of cc, dd.

I only need the records of first condition if exists. Else I want the records of second condition.

Is there any simpler approach for achieving this result in postgresql? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use window functions to determine if any of the rows are active:

```
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT f.*,
             BOOL_OR(Active) OVER () as any_active
      FROM Foo f
     ) f
WHERE any_active OR
      (NOT any_active AND DefaultValue);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want *only* rows that are `active` if there is at least one row that is `active`, and otherwise the default rows, then the following can already be enough:

```
with by_precedence as (
select
*
, case when Active = True then 0
       when defaultValue = True then 1
       else 2
  end as precedence
from foo
)
select *
from by_precedence b
where b.precedence in (select min(precedence) from by_precedence)
order by precedence
```

Otherwise, can you please edit your question and add more examples where the above doesn't do what you want?

```
id  name    defaultvalue    active  precedence
3   cc      f               t       0
4   dd      f               t       0
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/4f006/1)

Comment: Seems like you understood my problem and this is the result i want. Is this the simplest approach to my problem?

Comment: To me, it is the simplest approach because it remains quite testable if you want to see if the precedence order is what you want. I think you can get crafty with subselects instead of the CTE, but I like CTEs for their separability.